# How to disable progress icon of task terminal in Visual Studio code

Tags: icons, visual-studio-code, progress

There is a progress icon at the right of task title

[image]

I found it more a distraction than being useful, particularly for long running tasks. Is there a way to disable it ?

I don't see "Show Progress" :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer edited for correctness since initially, I misunderstood the question)

The setting is under File > Preferences > Settings > Features > Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Enable animation.

You can just type "progress" in search window and locate it under Features/Terminal

[image]

Comment: My bad. I checked and it is in  File > Preferences > Settings > Features > Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Enable animation.

You can just type "progress" in search window and locate it under Features/Terminal

https://imgur.com/AsliXuH